# Convert htaccess rules to nginx rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

I have these apache (htaccess) rules and I want to convert them to nginx rules. I have tried a lot of combinations but in vain.

You have the rules below:

```
RewriteRule ^candybooru/_images/([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{30}).*$  /candybooru/images/$1/$1$2
RewriteRule ^candybooru/_thumbs/([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{30}).*$  /candybooru/thumbs/$1/$1$2
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^candybooru/(.*)$ /candybooru/index.php?q=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use this page to convert the rules: http://winginx.com/en/htaccess

The converted rule is:

```
# nginx configuration
location / {
rewrite "^/candybooru/_images/([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{30}).*$" /candybooru/images/$1/$1$2;
rewrite "^/candybooru/_thumbs/([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{30}).*$" /candybooru/thumbs/$1/$1$2;
}
location /candybooru {
rewrite ^/candybooru/(.*)$ /candybooru/index.php?q=$1&$query_string;
}
```

Comment: If I already have a location / {} defined, I assume that I will add the first 2 rules in that location and then create another location for that candybooru right?

Comment: Yes, you can define many locations and location based rewrites in that way; for more information you can visit this page: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files

Comment: Already tried all the available online converters. The generated ruls are different and none of them works. I will keep digging. Thanks a lot for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Check out `try_files`. I haven't tested this, but it should work (or come close):

```
location /candybooru/ {
    location ~ "^/candybooru/_(images|thumbs)/([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{30})" {
        try_files /candybooru/$1/$2/$2$3 /candybooru/index.php?q=$2&$query_string;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am going to test it and get back to you. Hopefully it will just work! Thank you